# Why wrong answer for this simple calculation in Red language

Tags: rebol, arithmetic-expressions, red

I am trying to print correct value of simple expression: (100 - 55) / (100 - 75) but always getting 1.0 instead of 1.8. I have tried:

```
>> (100 - 55) / (100 - 75)
>> ((100 - 55) / (100 - 75))
>> to-float ((100 - 55) / (100 - 75))
>> probe ((100 - 55) / (100 - 75))
>> print ((100 - 55) / (100 - 75))
>> (divide (subtract 100 55)  (subtract 100 75))
```

They all give value of 1.0 or simply 1 when the correct values is obviously 1.8 (I have checked multiple times!). Where is the problem?

Edit: the output:

```
>> (100 - 55) / (100 - 75)
== 1
>> ((100 - 55) / (100 - 75))
== 1
>> to-float ((100 - 55) / (100 - 75))
== 1.0
>> probe ((100 - 55) / (100 - 75))
1
== 1
>> print ((100 - 55) / (100 - 75))
1
>> (divide (subtract 100 55)  (subtract 100 75))
== 1
>>
```

Red version 0.6.3 on Debian Stable Linux.

Comment: Can you paste the output from your console, and version of Red?  The result is fine in Rebol 2.

Comment: Output has been posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red does no automatic conversion from integer to float as Rebol does if all values are integer and the **best** result could be float.

You have to introduce a float value in your computation as in

```
>> (100 - 55) / (100 - 75.0)
== 1.8
```

but of course the earlier the better.

```
>> (to-float 100) - 55 / (100 - 75)
== 1.8
```

By the way I like to use

```
divide subtract to-float 100 55 subtract 100 75
```

You have to write a little bit more, but you save the parentheses and you do not have to think about precedence

Comment: Division of integers (unlike addition, subtraction and multiplication) is very likely to produce float values. Why this default behaviour?

Comment: Red is still evolving and my experience with it so far has been very good. Thank you all for your help. –

Comment: @rnso The auto-coercion to float values in math operations has not been implemented yet in Red. There will still be a way to avoid the auto-coercion though, when not wanted.

Comment: You don't actually have to think about precedence unlike the majority of programming languages, except for that special case of (binary) operators